# Which notation to use for "large arguments" in a function of two or more variables?

Tags: functions, notation

While performing some calculations it has often come up the gaussian integral. I use the notation:

$ I(A,B) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{A}{2}x^2 + Bx \right) \mathrm{d} x $

However this becomes cumbersome when A and B are themselves some expressions. For instance, in my case:

$ A = \frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\varepsilon}{m} \qquad B = \frac{i}{\hbar}\left(\dot{x}_n^i - \frac{1}{2} f^i(x_{n+1},t) - \frac{1}{2} f^i(x_n,t)\right)\varepsilon$

which results in:

$ I(A,B) = I\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\varepsilon}{m},\; \frac{i}{\hbar}\left(\dot{x}_n^i - \frac{1}{2} f^i(x_{n+1},t) - \frac{1}{2} f^i(x_n,t)\right)\varepsilon\right) $

I've also tried:

$ I(A,B)\bigg|_{A = \frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\varepsilon}{m},\; B = \frac{i}{\hbar}\left(\dot{x}_n^i - \frac{1}{2} f^i(x_{n+1},t) - \frac{1}{2} f^i(x_n,t)\right)\varepsilon} $

but I think it's worse.

I'd rather not "interrupt" calculations by introducing new variables midway and the long expression may obscure the comma between the arguments. Is there some (relatively common and understandable) notation which prevents this problem (or make it less significant)?

Comment: An easy visual trick is just to add more space around the comma (with `\;` or the like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the notation $I(A \mid B)$ instead of $I(A,B)$, resulting in
$$
   I(A,B) = I\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\varepsilon}{m} \;\middle|\;\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(\dot{x}_n^i - \frac{1}{2} f^i(x_{n+1},t) - \frac{1}{2} f^i(x_n,t)\right)\varepsilon\right).
$$
That way the separator doesn't get lost. This is not common notation, but not completely made up. I've seen it used for the same purpose with inner products and other two-parameter expressions, though not with $I(A,B)$ in particular.

To typeset this in LaTeX: I prefer `\mid` over `|` for a vertical separator, but LaTeX doesn't let you stretch `\mid`, so the second expression above uses `\middle|` with `\;`'s around it for manual spacing.